# Hi, I have a text(.txt) file that has millions of rows approx. 3 mil. I want to convert it into small SAS datasets (around 4)

Tags: sas, sas-studio

So i want to break down the txt file into multiple smaller sas datasets, can someone tell me how to do it, i searched a lot but nothings working.

I am doing it on sas studio

thanks!

I tried using macros, but the problem is i am unable to get my original variable names, and i am loosing data too

Comment: Can you please update your question to show the code you have tried?

Comment: What variable names? Do you have a program that can read the text file into a single dataset?  Why do you need it split? How do you want it split?  Do you want to make all of the smaller datasets at once? One at a time?  Do you want to re-read the text file for each of the target datasets?

Comment: Maybe this article will give you some inspiration: https://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2024/01/28/split-file-using-sas/

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a data step to read this in, you can do this fairly easily.

```
data want1 want2 want3 want4;
  infile yourfile;
  input [stuff];
  if _n_ lt 1000000 then output want1;
  else if _n_ lt 2000000 then output want2;
  else if _n_ lt 3000000 then output want3;
  else output want4;
run;
```

Fairly straightforward.